# Change the value of a column based on the groupby shift and also create new column - Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Session      slot_num         ID    prob
s1           1                A     0.2
s1           2                B     0.9
s1           2                B     0.4
s1           3                C     0.7
s1           4                D     0.8
s1           4                D     0.3
s1           5                E     0.6
s1           6                F     0.5
s1           7                G     0.7
s2           1                A1    0.6
s2           2                B1    0.5
s2           3                C1    1.1
s2           3                C1    0.6
s2           4                D1    0.7
s2           5                E1    0.6
s2           6                F1    0.7
s2           7                G1    1.2
s2           7                G1    0.7
```

which is sorted as shown below

```
df = df.sort_values(['Session', 'slot_num'], ascending=True)
```

Then I would like to create new column called overbook as explained below.

if we have more than one same Session and slot_num
first one as 'yes', second one 'booking', if there is more all other than 
first one is booking
else:
   df['overbook'] = 'no'

Also replace the ID of the second row as 'TBF'

Expected Output:

```
Session      slot_num         ID    prob    overbook
s1           1                A     0.2     no
s1           2                B     0.9     yes
s1           2               TBF    0.4     booking
s1           3                C     0.7     no
s1           4                D     0.8     yes
s1           4               TBF    0.3     booking
s1           5                E     0.6     no
s1           6                F     0.5     no
s1           7                G     0.7     no
s2           1                A1    0.6     no
s2           2                B1    0.5     no
s2           3                C1    1.1     yes
s2           3                TBF   0.6     booking
s2           4                D1    0.7     no
s2           5                E1    0.6     no
s2           6                F1    0.7     no
s2           7                G1    1.2     yes
s2           7                TBF   0.7     booking
```

Comment: Can you explain more `if Session and slot_num is same as above` ?

Comment: @jezrael then make first one of the overbook as yes, second on booking, if there exist third one make it as also booking

Comment: Sorry, not understand, how you get if it is overbook?

Comment: @jezrael edited the question... Sorry it is my bad.. I explained very badly.

Comment: Is correct `s2           2                B1    0.5     no, 
s2           2                C1    1.1     yes` ?

Comment: @jezrael sorry that is also my bad edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212782/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).

Comment: It seems `s2` group output is not correct, I hope Imy answer is what need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by counter created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), but only for duplciated rows so used [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['Session', 'slot_num'], ascending=True)

m = df.duplicated(['Session', 'slot_num'], keep=False)
s = df.groupby(['Session', 'slot_num']).cumcount()
d = {0:'yes', 1:'booking'}
df['overbook'] = np.where(m, s.map(d), 'no')
print (df)
   Session  slot_num  ID  prob overbook
0       s1         1   A   0.2       no
1       s1         2   B   0.9      yes
2       s1         2   B   0.4  booking
3       s1         3   C   0.7       no
4       s1         4   D   0.8      yes
5       s1         4   D   0.3  booking
6       s1         5   E   0.6       no
7       s1         6   F   0.5       no
8       s1         7   G   0.7       no
9       s2         1  A1   0.6       no
10      s2         2  B1   0.5       no
11      s2         3  C1   1.1      yes
12      s2         3  C1   0.6  booking
13      s2         4  D1   0.7       no
14      s2         5  E1   0.6       no
15      s2         6  F1   0.7       no
16      s2         7  G1   1.2      yes
17      s2         7  G1   0.7  booking
```

Comment: changed the input as you pointed above.. pls change your input.. 11      s2         2  C1   1.1  as    11      s2         3  C1   1.1  booking

Comment: @ALI - thank you, today is one deadline... So not easy my mind ;)

Comment: Please look into this question if you have time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889550/calculate-specific-function-from-the-date-column-and-input-parameter-specified-b

Comment: @Danish Sorry, I am offline, on phone only 3 times daily this week.