# Calculate specific function from the Date column and input parameter specified by user in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below.

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-03             23              
2020-02-06             14           
2020-02-09             23
2020-02-10             23  
2020-02-11             23          
2020-02-13             30            
2020-02-20             29            
2020-02-29             100
2020-03-01             38
2020-03-10             38               
2020-03-11             38                    
2020-03-26             70           
2020-03-29             70
```

From that I would like to create a function that will calculate the column called t_function based on the calculated values t1, t2 and t3 .

where user will enter following parameters.

```
Step1:
Enter start_date1 = 2020-02-01
Enter end_date1 =  2020-02-06
Enter a0 = 3
Enter a1 = 1
Enter a2 = 0

calculate t1 as number of days from start_date1 (2020-02-01) to the values in date column till end_date1.
t_function = a0 + a1*t1 + a2*(t1)**2

Step2:
Enter start_date2 = 2020-02-13
Enter end_date2 =  2020-02-29
Enter a0 = 2
Enter a1 = 0
Enter a2 = 1
calculate time_in_days as t2, which is 1 on start_date2 = 2020-02-13 and so on till end_date2
t_function = a0 + a1*t2 + a2*(t2)**2


Step3:
Enter start_date3 = 2020-03-11
Enter end_date3 =  2020-03-29
Enter a0 = 4
Enter a1 = 0
Enter a2 = 0
calculate time_in_days as t3, which is 1 on start_date2 = 2020-02-13 and so on till end_date2
t_function = t_function = a0 + a1*t3 + a2*(t3)**2
```

Expected output:

```
Date                t_factor     t1         t2         t3       t_function
2020-02-01             5          1         NaN        NaN      4
2020-02-03             23         3         NaN        NaN      6
2020-02-06             14         6         NaN        NaN      9
2020-02-09             23         NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN
2020-02-10             23         NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN
2020-02-11             23         NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN
2020-02-13             30         NaN        1         NaN      3   
2020-02-20             29         NaN        8         NaN      66
2020-02-29             100        NaN        17        NaN      291
2020-03-01             38         NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN
2020-03-10             38         NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN
2020-03-11             38         NaN       NaN        1        4 
2020-03-26             70         NaN       NaN        15       4
2020-03-29             70         NaN       NaN        18       4
```

Note:
Initial start_date ie start_date1 should first date of Date column.
Final end_date is end_date3 should be final date of Date column.
The column t_factor is not used.

I tried below code to calculate t1 after that I am confused. Since I am new in python and pandas

```
df['t1'] = (df['Date'] - df.at[0, 'Date']).dt.days + 1
```

Comment: Could you clarify "calculate t1 as number of days from start_date1 (2020-02-01) to the values in date column till end_date1."

Comment: @quest start_date1 is 2020-02-01, so t1 for that is 1, 
for second row Date = 2020-02-03 which is in between start_date1 and end_date1,
so t1 = (2020-02-03 -  2020-02-01) days + 1

Comment: If I understand correctly, t1, t2, and t3 are calculated as the difference from the first day in the group +1. But - how do you calculate t_function? What's the logic for this one?

Comment: @Roy2012 you are correct.. 

t_function = a0 + a1*t1 + a2*(t1)**2

where in each step user can change a0, a1 and a2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-03             23              
2020-02-06             14           
2020-02-09             23           
2020-02-13             30            
2020-02-20             29            
2020-02-29             100               
2020-03-11             38                    
2020-03-26             70           
2020-03-29             70 """), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[0])
df

def fun(x, start="2020-02-01", end="2020-02-06", a0=3, a1=1, a2=0):
    start = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
    end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if start <= x.Date <= end:
        t2 = (x.Date - start)/np.timedelta64(1, 'D') + 1
        diff = a0 + a1*t2 + a2*(t2)**2
    else:
        diff = np.NaN
    return diff

df["t1"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
df["t2"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x, "2020-02-13", "2020-02-29", 2, 0, 1), axis=1)
df["t3"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x, "2020-03-11", "2020-03-29", 4, 0, 0), axis=1)
df["t_function"] =  df["t1"].fillna(0) + df["t2"].fillna(0) + df["t3"].fillna(0)

df
```

Here is the output:

```
 Date   t_factor    t1  t2    t3    t_function
0   2020-02-01  5   4.0 NaN   NaN   4.0
1   2020-02-03  23  6.0 NaN   NaN   6.0
2   2020-02-06  14  9.0 NaN   NaN   9.0
3   2020-02-09  23  NaN NaN   NaN   0.0
4   2020-02-13  30  NaN 3.0   NaN   3.0
5   2020-02-20  29  NaN 66.0  NaN   66.0
6   2020-02-29  100 NaN 291.0 NaN   291.0
7   2020-03-11  38  NaN NaN   4.0   4.0
8   2020-03-26  70  NaN NaN   4.0   4.0
9   2020-03-29  70  NaN NaN   4.0   4.0
```

Comment: please share your output

Comment: Thank you so much, this calculates t1, t2 and t3.. Please help me to calculate t_function

Comment: ah, no worries. Here is the complete sol. Wanted to let to do the missing part. I think you have a calculation mistake in the desired output in your question.

Comment: is there any way where we can automate using for loop.

if user wants to calculate t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 and t6 and check automatically how many t's user wants to calculate based on user input

Comment: instead of  - >   df["t_function"] = col1.fillna(0) + col2.fillna(0) + col3.fillna(0)

we have to replace by df["t_function"] = df["t1"].fillna(0) + df["t2"].fillna(0) + df["t3"].fillna(0)

Comment: Yes, sure you can have a loop and add as many cols as you please. You will have to store the input parameters in a list and loop over. Sorry for the `col` was a copy paste error on my side.

Comment: added similar question to loop over the dictionary.
Please look into this during your free time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894169/create-a-specific-column-by-looping-over-the-user-defined-dictionary-in-pandas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217803/discussion-between-danish-and-quest).