# Create a specific column by looping over the user defined dictionary in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df as shown below.

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-03             23              
2020-02-06             14           
2020-02-09             23
2020-02-10             23  
2020-02-11             23          
2020-02-13             30            
2020-02-20             29            
2020-02-29             100
2020-03-01             38
2020-03-10             38               
2020-03-11             38                    
2020-03-26             70           
2020-03-29             70
```

From that I would like to create a function that will calculate the column called t_function based on the calculated values t1, t2 and t3.

where input parameters are stored in a dictionary as shown below.

```
d1 = {'b1': {'s': '2020-02-01', 'e':'2020-02-06', 'coef':[3, 1, 0]},
     'b2': {'s': '2020-02-13', 'e':'2020-02-29', 'coef':[2, 0, 1]},
     'b3': {'s': '2020-03-11', 'e':'2020-03-29', 'coef':[4, 0, 0]}}
```

Expected output:

```
Date                t_factor     t1         t2         t3       t_function
2020-02-01             5          4         NaN        NaN      4
2020-02-03             23         6         NaN        NaN      6
2020-02-06             14         9         NaN        NaN      9
2020-02-09             23         NaN       NaN        NaN      0
2020-02-10             23         NaN       NaN        NaN      0
2020-02-11             23         NaN       NaN        NaN      0
2020-02-13             30         NaN       3          NaN      3   
2020-02-20             29         NaN       66         NaN      66
2020-02-29             100        NaN       291        NaN      291
2020-03-01             38         NaN       NaN        NaN      0
2020-03-10             38         NaN       NaN        NaN      0
2020-03-11             38         NaN       NaN        4        4 
2020-03-26             70         NaN       NaN        4        4
2020-03-29             70         NaN       NaN        4        4
```

I tried below code

```
def fun(x, start="2020-02-01", end="2020-02-06", a0=3, a1=1, a2=0):
    start = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
    end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if start <= x.Date <= end:
        t2 = (x.Date - start)/np.timedelta64(1, 'D') + 1
        diff = a0 + a1*t2 + a2*(t2)**2
    else:
        diff = np.NaN
    return diff

df["t1"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
df["t2"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x, "2020-02-13", "2020-02-29", 2, 0, 1), axis=1)
df["t3"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x, "2020-03-11", "2020-03-29", 4, 0, 0), axis=1)
df["t_function"] = df['t1'].fillna(0) + df['t2'].fillna(0) + df['t3'].fillna(0)
```

Above code I would like change by looping over the dictionary d1.

Note:

The dictionary d1 may have more than three keys such as 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4' then we have to create t1, t2, t3 and t4 columns. I would like to automate this with looping over the dictionary d1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose that you store the data as a list of tuples. Like so,

```
params = [('2020-02-01', '2020-02-06', 3, 1, 0), 
        ('2020-02-13', '2020-02-29', 2, 0, 1),
        ('2020-03-11', '2020-03-29', 4, 0, 0)]
```

Now all you need is to loop over  `params` and add the columns to your dataframe `df`.

```
total = None
for i, param in enumerate(params):
    s, e, a0, a1, a2 = param
    df[f"t{i+1}"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x, s, e, a0, a1, a2), axis=1)
    if i==0:
        total = df[f"t{i+1}"].fillna(0)
    else: 
        total += df[f"t{i+1}"].fillna(0)
df["t_function"] = total
```

This gives the desired output:

```
    Date    t_factor    t1  t2  t3  t_function
0   2020-02-01  5   4.0 NaN NaN 4.0
1   2020-02-03  23  6.0 NaN NaN 6.0
2   2020-02-06  14  9.0 NaN NaN 9.0
3   2020-02-09  23  NaN NaN NaN 0.0
4   2020-02-10  23  NaN NaN NaN 0.0
5   2020-02-11  23  NaN NaN NaN 0.0
6   2020-02-13  30  NaN 3.0 NaN 3.0
7   2020-02-20  29  NaN 66.0    NaN 66.0
8   2020-02-29  100 NaN 291.0   NaN 291.0
9   2020-03-01  38  NaN NaN NaN 0.0
10  2020-03-10  38  NaN NaN NaN 0.0
11  2020-03-11  38  NaN NaN 4.0 4.0
12  2020-03-26  70  NaN NaN 4.0 4.0
13  2020-03-29  70  NaN NaN 4.0 4.0
```

Comment: How can I add over the loop itself to calculate t_function

other than adding like this df["t_function"] = df['t1'].fillna(0) + df['t2'].fillna(0) + df['t3'].fillna(0)

Comment: The above code is not working for me, can you please share your output